# How to resolve Pentaho JPivot Resultset Overflow?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

My logs table contains more than 9 lacks records and i'm using the following query

```
Select date_format(time,"%d-%m-%y") as day,uri,1 as count from logs;
```

Query gives the overflow exception in JPIVOT PENTAHO Community Edition